# Using require js getting undefined for all modules other than jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs

My jQuery library is getting loaded, but I'm getting an undefined error for any other modules I'm importing. Most of them have a jQuery dependency, which I shim in. Can anyone tell me why all my other modules are undefined?

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: 'js',
    shim: {
        'jqueryui': ['jquery'],
        'dynatree': ['jquery'],
        'noty'    : ['jquery']
    },
    paths: {
        jquery: 'vendor/jquery',
        jqueryui: 'vendor/jqueryui',
        dynatree: '../includes/dynatree/jquery.dynatree.min',
        jsPlumb: '../includes/jsPlumb/dist/js/jquery.jsPlumb-1.5.5-min',
        noty: '../includes/noty/packaged/jquery.noty.packaged.min'
    }
});

requirejs(['jquery', 'jqueryui', 'dynatree', 'jsPlumb', 'noty'],
    function ( $, jqueryui, dynatree, jsPlumb, noty ) {

        console.log('hello', $, noty, jsPlumb, dynatree);
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jquery ui` doesn't export anything, it uses the same `jquery` symbol. I'd say the same applies for the rest of the libraries.

Even in the case they'd export something, it won't work because you're not setting the export symbol for your shims. Here you have an example of a shim with export

```
shim: {
    'backbone': {
        deps: ['underscore', 'jquery'],
        //Once loaded, use the global 'Backbone' as the module value.
        exports: 'Backbone'
    },
}
```

I'd replace your code by

```
requirejs(['jquery', 'jqueryui', 'dynatree', 'jsPlumb', 'noty'],
    function ($) { // $ is the only symbol that needs to be used

    });
```

Comment: jsPlumb should have it's own object and methods. I tried using that and still got undefined. I'll try adding an export method to it.

Comment: @Organiccat: I don't see `jsPlumb` on your shim configuration. Try to shim this library using the export setting as I showed on my example.

Comment: Yep, that was the problem, I added the correct deps and exported when required and that fixed it. Thanks!